Creating a column with optimize (thumbnail) image to be used in PowerBI
I am building a report in PowerBI with content from a Sharepoint list. Everything looks good but the images are the original size, some 2,3 MB and I have over 300 making this report super big.
How can I create a new instance of the image in Sharepoint to be used on PowerBI? I only need images 200 x 200 max.
